# Node.js shrinkwrapped package.json causes npm install to update new versions regardless

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

I've got a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and a `package.json` in a git branch called "deployment".

On my servers, I fetch and merge this deployment branch from github. This ensures that my servers have the latest deployment version.

Because the node_modules binaries etc. are not being shipped, I need to run `npm install` or `npm update` on the server side too, after the project repository has been pulled from the server.

This is why I decided to use `npm shrinkwrap`. However, even when I have this `npm-shrinkwrap.json` in the main folder and run `npm install`, it still installs newer versions of submodules, even though the shrinkwrapped json file has locked these down. It seems like npm does not even look at the shrinkwrap file.

Could anyone explain why this happens, and how to resolve this situation?

This is part of `package.json`:

```
"dependencies" : {
    "eventemitter2" : "0.4.9",
    "after"         : "0.4.1",
    "express"       : "2.5.9"
},
"devDependencies" : {
    "mocha"     : ">= 1.0.3 < 2",
    "should"    : ">= 0.6.3 < 1",
    "request"   : ">= 2.9.202 < 3",
    "commander" : ">= 0.6.0 < 1"
},
```

Whereas `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "eventemitter2": {
      "version": "0.4.9"
    },
    "after": {
      "version": "0.4.1"
    },
    "express": {
      "version": "2.5.9",
      "dependencies": {
        "connect": {
          "version": "1.8.7",
          "dependencies": {
            "formidable": {
              "version": "1.0.9"
            }
          }
        },
        "mime": {
          "version": "1.2.4"
        },
        "qs": {
          "version": "0.4.2"
        },
        "mkdirp": {
          "version": "0.3.0"
        }
      }
    },
    "commander": {
      "version": "0.6.0"
    },
    "should": {
      "version": "0.6.3"
    },
    "request": {
      "version": "2.9.202"
    }
  }
}
```

Yet, when I ran `npm install` it updated `qs` from version 0.4.2 to version 0.5.0. Also, it updated `mime` to 1.2.5. Why did it do this?

The `npm install` returned this:

```
qs@0.5.0 ./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/qs
mime@1.2.5 ./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/mime
```

Interestingly enough the shrinkwrap contains neither of these. I guess this is the problem. Now the question is why it did not contain these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `npm-shrinkwrap.json` doesn't include connect's version of qs. You should `npm install` before you generate your shrinkwrap.