# Using a repository as an npm dependency in meteor

Tags: meteor, npm

I forked and changed an npm module today ([node-cldr](https://github.com/Nemo64/node-cldr)). Now I want to test if it still works with my meteor package ([nemo64:translator](https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-translator)). I found out that the less package [has a way of referencing a commit on github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/fca5c382d5c25e23c962755e08a1ce7230df6e20#L14). That did not work in my case. This is what happens if i try to run `meteor test-packages ./`:

```
npm ERR! Error: Problems were encountered
npm ERR! Please correct and try again.
npm ERR! missing: node-cldr@https://github.com/Nemo64/node-cldr/tarball/ea7e32150eb11418803760f87ff3958f569599b7, required by packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-16i2g97@0.0.0
npm ERR! extraneous: cldr@2.2.1 /data/marco/Git/meteor/nemo64:translator/.npm/plugin/language-compiler-new-ee22eu/node_modules/cldr
npm ERR!     at shrinkwrap_ (/home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/shrinkwrap.js:30:15)
npm ERR!     at /home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/shrinkwrap.js:24:5
npm ERR!     at /home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/ls.js:44:30
npm ERR!     at /home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:130:5
npm ERR!     at /home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:244:14
npm ERR!     at cb (/home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:244:14
npm ERR!     at cb (/home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:244:14
npm ERR!     at cb (/home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/home/marco/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.d1izik++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm" "shrinkwrap"
npm ERR! cwd /data/marco/Git/meteor/nemo64:translator/.npm/plugin/language-compiler-new-ee22eu
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/marco/Git/meteor/nemo64:translator/.npm/plugin/language-compiler-new-ee22eu/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building plugin `language-compiler` in package `nemo64:translator`:
error: couldn't run `npm shrinkwrap`
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js shrinkwrapped package.json causes npm install to update new versions regardless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672912/node-js-shrinkwrapped-package-json-causes-npm-install-to-update-new-versions-reg)